# jquery ajax request does not return expected content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new to jQuery and Ajax. I'm following a tutorial, and having a problem with this.

I have an anchor tag with id `getcomments` and the following JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
   $('#getcomments').click(function() {
       $.ajax({
          url       : "req.html",
          success   : function(response) {
               console.log(response);
          }
       });
       return false;
   });
});
```

And an HTML file called `req.html` in the same folder with a mock comment.

When I inspect the log I only get the "document" in firebug, and no actual get request.

I've tried doing something actual in the success function also, appending the response.

Nothing happens, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `req.html` look like?

Comment: you could use console.log() in the first line of the click function to check if the event is triggered and perhaps provide us with some more info.

Comment: How do i provide the html? it dosent allow me to post the html here

Comment: @Paragonbliss Of course it does. Make it be code. `<script>` tags are HTML, btw.

Comment: Use a jsFiddle to post your thml and javascript and link to it

Comment: Is there an error in your javascript that has prevented your code from executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a local file it won't make a request.

That you see `Document` in Firebug means it's working. Set the contents of a div to the response, after adding a `dataType: "html"` to the Ajax call--it will be the contents of the HTML file.

```
  $(function() {
    $('#getcomments').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
           url       : "req.html",
           dataType  : "html",
           success   : function(response) {
             $("#foo").append(response);
                console.log(response);
           }
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: How do i do that, im not entirely sure how you mean

Comment: @Paragonbliss How do you do what? Cut and paste?

Comment: Sorry  the  code wasent there when i commented, but thank you very much that worked, before the datatype i tried what you said, but i was getting an error saying the node couldent be inserted in the hierachy at that point, anyways sorry i am so newbish to this, but this helped me, thank you :)

Comment: @Paragonbliss It was assuming an XML document; clicking on the `Document` line in Firebug will show you what the browser (thinks it) knows about the requested document. Glad you worked it out :)